# Highlight definition of occurences of a function/immutable in LightTable

Tags: clojure, syntax-highlighting, lighttable

Is it somehow possible to highlight all occurrences of a function and (jump to) its definition in the Clojure-editor LightTable?

If I for example have the following code

```
(defn a [x] (* x x))
(str "abc" (a 4))
;; ... some more code  ...
(a 2)
```

When I'm with my cursor at one of the a's, I'd like to have all a's that are related to the function beeing highlighted. So the `a` in the String `abc` should not be highlighted.

It would be also nice to jump directly to the point where `a` is defined. (I tried `Strg + .`, but that did not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting functionality is implemented through a plugin, just go to "Plugin Manager" and search for `match-highlighter`. If you don't like the style you just need to fork the project and tweak the CSS

If you fancy to collaborate:

https://github.com/Gozala/lt.plugins.match-highlighter

The *jump to definition* hasn't being implemented yet afaik, keep an eye on the list of plugins if you fancy something else

https://github.com/LightTable/plugin-metadata